# Segmentation fault and wav file reader

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I decided to play with C++ on audio algorithm, being more used to Matlab I struggle a bit.

First step is to record a wav file into an array, using sndfile library.
I used the examples from the library :

https://github.com/michaelwu/libsndfile/blob/master/examples/sfprocess.c

I want to create a wavF class which contains the general information of the wav (sampling frequency,channels... ) and the data of the wav file for further treatments.

I have almost achieve this but there is a segmentation fault occurring  when entering in the `while ((readcount = sf_read_double (infile, data, BUFFER_LEN)))`  loop (but not always) in the wavfile.cpp. I can't figure out why.

I want to save the wav data in the array double* m_wavData, using the function process_data in the class constructor with a buffer loop.

Here his the codes:

The main:

```
#include    <sndfile.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    "wavfile.h"


int main (void)
{
    SNDFILE      *infile ;
    const char  *infilename = "Piano_mf_Gb2.wav" ;
    SndfileHandle file;
    file=SndfileHandle(infilename);

    int test(initwav(infile, file, infilename));
    if(test==1) return 0 ;

    wavF wav1(infile, file, infilename);

    sf_close (infile) ;
    /* Close input and output files. */


    return 0 ;
} /* main */
```

The header:

```
    #ifndef WAVFILE_H_INCLUDED
#define WAVFILE_H_INCLUDED

#define BUFFER_LEN  1024
#include    <sndfile.hh>

class wavF
{
    public:
    wavF(SNDFILE  *infile, SndfileHandle file,const char * fName);
    wavF(const unsigned int wavsize,const unsigned int channels,const unsigned int samplerate,const char * fileName);
    ~wavF();

    protected:
         const unsigned int m_wavsize;
         const unsigned int m_channels;
         const unsigned int m_samplerate;

        const char * m_fileName;
        double * m_wavData;

};
static void process_data (double *wavData, double * data, int count, int channels);
int initwav(SNDFILE  *infile,SndfileHandle file,const char * fName);
#endif // WAVFILE_H_INCLUDED
```

and the code wavfile.cpp

```
   #include "wavfile.h"

wavF::wavF(SNDFILE  *infile, SndfileHandle file,const char * fName): m_channels(file.channels()),m_samplerate(file.samplerate()),m_wavsize(file.frames()),m_fileName(fName)
{
     /* This is a buffer of double precision floating point values
    ** which will hold our data while we process it.
    */
    static double data [BUFFER_LEN] ;
    //initialise class array
    double* m_wavData = new double[m_wavsize*m_channels] ;


    printf ("Opened file '%s'\n", m_fileName) ;
    printf ("Sample rate : %d\n", m_samplerate) ;
    printf ("Channels    : %d\n", m_channels) ;
    printf ("Size    : %d\n", m_wavsize) ;

    puts ("") ;

    //fill array with the wav channel
    int readcount(0);
    int counter(0);
    while ((readcount = sf_read_double (infile, data, BUFFER_LEN)))
    {
     //  printf("%i \n",counter);
      // counter++;
       process_data (m_wavData,data, readcount, m_channels) ;
    } ;

  /* RAII takes care of destroying SndfileHandle object. */
} /* read_file */

wavF::wavF(const unsigned int wavsize,const unsigned int channels,const unsigned int samplerate,const char * fileName):
m_channels(channels),m_samplerate(samplerate),m_wavsize(wavsize),m_fileName(fileName)
{
}

static void process_data (double *m_wavData,double *data, int count, int channels)
{
    int k;

    /* Process the data here.
    ** If the soundfile contains more then 1 channel you need to take care of
    ** the data interleaving youself.
    */

    for (k = 0 ; k < channels*count ; k ++)
            m_wavData [k] = data[k] ;
} /* process_data */

wavF::~wavF()
{
    delete  m_wavData;
    printf("array is detroyed");
}

int initwav(SNDFILE  *infile,SndfileHandle file, const char * fName)
{

    SF_INFO     sfinfo ;
        if (! (infile = sf_open (fName, SFM_READ, &sfinfo)))
    {   /* Open failed so print an error message. */
        printf ("Not able to open input file %s.\n", fName) ;
        puts (sf_strerror (NULL)) ;
        return 1;
    } ;
    return 0;
}
```

What coding heresy did I write ? Any advices?

(audio wav found on uiowa.edu database)
Thank You.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I'm using code::blocks, the problems is that when i use the debugger there is no error, only when i build and run. I'll work on a more minimal one

Comment: You probably confuse the debugger with the compiler. The debugger can be used to run your program with break points set and step through the code line by line. You can watch the current variable values after each step.

Comment: Fyi, `double* m_wavData = ...` in your constructor body *hides* the member variable `double* m_wavData`, leaving the member completely uninitialized (it doesn't appear in your member-initializer list either). I sincerely doubt you meant to do that.

Comment: In `initwav`, you're assigning to the parameter `infile`. This has no effect on the variable whose value you passed.

Comment: data is a buffer of BUFFER_LEN doubles.

But sf_read_double reads channels + items

You should declare it with BUFFER_LEN*nb_channels, thus not statically like you did since nb_channels is only known at run time.

Comment: @molbdnilo True but why ?  `infile` is a pointer and should contains the informations.

Comment: @Boulgour The parameter contains the *value* of the variable you passed, just like if it were an `int`. There's nothing magic about pointers. If you want the function to modify a variable, you need to pass a pointer or reference to that variable.

Comment: @molbdnilo ok , passed a pointer containing the pointer adress infile to change the value now it works! Thank you –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all !
They were several mistakes:
1) As pointed out by Jean-François Fabre, the buffer size wasn't correct, leading in trying to write data in the array `m_wavData` taking value out of the array containing the wav values`data`.
---> `m_wavData = new double[m_wavsize*m_channels] ;`

2)  As pointed out by WhozCraig I was re-declaring the variable  `m_wavData` in the constructor of the class leading in hiding the member variale of the same name. --> erased re-declaration.

3) As pointed out by molbdnilo the  parameter `infile` add no effect in the way i used it leading in not reading the wav data.
-->worked around the problem by opening in the init and in the constructor.

4) I was continuously writing the same case of the array `m_wavData` (size of the buffer).
--> added counter to write in the good cases.

Here is my solution in a more minimal version(πάντα ῥεῖ):

```
#include    <sndfile.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_LEN  1024
#include    <sndfile.hh>
class wavF
{
    public:
    wavF(SNDFILE  *infile, SndfileHandle file,const char * fName);
    void prinvalue(int k);// help to see if the values are good
    ~wavF();

    protected:
          unsigned int m_wavsize;
          unsigned int m_channels;
          unsigned int m_samplerate;

        const char * m_fileName;
        double * m_wavData;

};

int main(void)
{
    // initiate variables to open the file
    SNDFILE     *infile ;
    const char  *infilename = "test.wav" ;
    SndfileHandle file;
    file=SndfileHandle(infilename);

        SF_INFO     sfinfo ;
        if (! (infile = sf_open (infilename, SFM_READ, &sfinfo)))
    {   /* Open failed so print an error message. */
        printf ("Not able to open input file %s.\n", infilename) ;
        puts (sf_strerror (NULL)) ;
        return 1;
    } ;

    wavF wav1(infile, file, infilename);
    wav1.prinvalue(1000);//test if the value inside of the wav is correct

    sf_close (infile);
    /* Close input and output files. */


    return 0 ;
}

void wavF::prinvalue(int k)
{
    printf("the value is %lf",m_wavData[k]);
}

wavF::wavF(SNDFILE  *infile, SndfileHandle file,const char * fName):m_channels(file.channels()),m_samplerate(file.samplerate()),m_wavsize(file.frames()),m_fileName(fName)
{   //declaration of the allocated arrays
    static double* data= new double [BUFFER_LEN*m_channels] ;
    m_wavData = new double[m_wavsize*m_channels] ;

    printf ("Opened file '%s'\n", m_fileName) ;
    printf ("Sample rate : %d\n", m_samplerate) ;
    printf ("Channels    : %d\n", m_channels) ;
    printf ("Size    : %d\n", m_wavsize) ;
    puts ("") ;

    int readcount(0);//number of data in the buffer
    int counter(0);// number of time buffer is used
    while ((readcount = sf_read_double (infile, data, BUFFER_LEN*m_channels)))
    {
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < readcount ; k ++)
        {
             m_wavData[counter*readcount+k] = data[k] ;//put data in the array
        }
        counter++;
        printf("the wav value is %lf \n",m_wavData[counter*readcount-1]);//look if the stored values are good
    } ;
    delete[] data; //clear allocated buffer array
} /* read_file */


wavF::~wavF()
{
    delete[] m_wavData;
}
```